# jQuery animate() does not work with If-Else Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery beginner here. I'm trying to get a group of divs to change from red to blue when I click on them. When I click them again, I want the divs to change back to red. I tried using jQuery's animate() method (with the jQuery color plugin) to change the div's color. However, the code below only partially works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div").click(function() {
        $("div").each(function() {
            if (this.style.color !== "blue") {
                $(this).animate({   
                    color:'blue'
                },1000);
            } else {
                this.style.color = "red";
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

When I click a div, the if statement works fine. The divs change to blue. However, when I click a div again, the divs don't change back to red. The else statement doesn't seem to work. Any ideas on my mistake? The else statement works when I replace `$(this).animate({...})` with `this.style.color = "blue";` which so I think I'm doing something wrong with the animate() method.

Here is the HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title> each() test1 </title> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
    body{
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    div {
        font-size: 3em;
        color: #ff0000;
        text-align: center;
        cursor:pointer;
        font-weight: bolder;
        width: 300px;
    }
    </style> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div> Click here </div> 
    <div> to iterate through </div> 
    <div> these divs </div> 
</body>
<script src="theJavaScriptFile.js"> </script> 
</html>
```

Comment: did you try $(this).css("color","red") ?

Comment: It’s likely never `"blue"`. Please use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and use `console.log(this.style.color);` to debug this.

Comment: if you console.log this.style.color right before the if statement, what do you get?

Comment: @nixkuroi nothing, the console.log worked, but it returned blank.

Comment: @AlexFidelChen For both times when you click?

Comment: Where is the color being set initially?  Is it a class, or inline style?

Comment: Under <style> in my html file, div {
  color: #ff0000;
  
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use `blue` or `red` color codes. It will get converted to RGB code.
For example `this.style.color` will be `RGB(0,0,255)` not `blue` so your expression always returns `true` no matter what color is it.

I create this example in different color mode for you to take a look https://jsfiddle.net/3tpncgr1/1/

Anyway, if you want to have special logic for particular color then keep using this approach. Otherwise, use class name instead of color code to determine. Because browsers always return `rgb` value for `color` attribute

Comment: I tried your example. When I click a div, the divs turn blue, but they don't change back to red upon another click.

Comment: Sorry, I fogot to save it. Try it here https://jsfiddle.net/3tpncgr1/1/

Comment: @HungCao Your example works thanks. I did notice that your example stops working when I take out the spaces between the commas, meaning I change `rgb(0, 0, 255)` to `rgb(0,0,255)`. Any ideas why?

Comment: because, you are comparing 2 strings. So it requires exact match. If you want to remove all spaces before comparing then use regex `this.style.color.replace(/\s+/g, '') === 'rgb(0,0,255)'`

Comment: So my if statement's conditional cannot be `(this.style.color !== "#0000ff")` because the browser won't read "#0000ff" as the same as "rgb(0, 0, 255)"? Because the strings are not exactly the same?

Comment: Correct! it's a default behavior. You can always convert them if you really want.

Answer (score 0):

I would manage it by using a active class to control the states.

In that case I would succes changing

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div").click(function() {
       $.each( $(this).parent().children("div"),function() {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
              $(this).addClass('active');
                $(this).animate({   
                    color:'blue'
                },1000);
            } else {
              $(this).removeClass('active');
                this.style.color = "red";
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title> each() test1 </title> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
    body{
        background-color: #000000;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    div.active{  }
    div {
        font-size: 1em;
        color: #ff0000;
        text-align: center;
        cursor:pointer;
        font-weight: bolder;
        width: 300px;
    }
    </style> 
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="containerOne">
    <div> Click here </div> 
    <div> to iterate through </div> 
    <div> these divs </div>
  </div>
    <div id="containerTwo">
    <div> Click here </div> 
    <div> to iterate through </div> 
    <div> these divs </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="theJavaScriptFile.js"> </script> 
</html>
```